# What is best solution for user registration?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, registration

I have django-rest-framework backend and React frontend.
I want to use SSO (*Single Sign-On*).
JWT token will be used for registration and authentification.

**What is the best approach for registration?**

1. Using front-end in this case will make two requests to SSO for registration (*getting JWT*) and to back-end with data.
2. Front-end make only one request to back-end with data and registration will be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON webtokens works of registration.
there is an option to add Refresh tokens with JSON tokens but needs more work, secure 
 tokens against XSS attacks, then u r good to go :)